# openssl shared libraries hot-replace upgrade

Tags: openssl, upgrade

Please confirm (or reject) my statement : it is abolutelly legal to replace old openssl library with new one, in terms of upgrade process .

It is true ?

- Of course my application uses openssl shared library, and loaded it dynamically .
- Old and new libraries supposed to be build with same compiler with same options .

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is abolutelly legal to replace old openssl library with new one, in terms of upgrade process .

No, its not true. Also see [Binary Compatibility](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binary_Compatibility) on the OpenSSL wiki. The [OpenSSL FAQ](http://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html) has some information, too.

If you omitted the word *"absolutely"*, then I would have said *"it depends"*. I read *"absolutely"* to mean *"its always the case"*.